# ObservableCollection in C#

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

What's the best way to populate a collection with multiple data?

```
var query = (from p in obsDay where p.courseFaculty == "abellana" select p);

foreach (var item in query)
{
   facultyTime.Add(
      new TimePerDay() 
          { subjTime = 
              new ObservableCollection<TimeSpan> 
                  { item.courseTimeStart } 
          }
      ); 
}
availProf[randomNumber].actualTime = facultyTime;
```

I tried this one but it only adds one data on my collection? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your `query` is useless.

Comment: Which collection does it only add one to? And how many were in te query?

Comment: What Slaks means is that you can just foreach over obsDay

Comment: It only adds one data to facultyTime collection where it suppose to be there should be like 1 Professor with x days(mon-fri) with times per day. There was only one query, which was the first data that it received.

Comment: What type is 'facultyTime'? I assume it is DateTime.

Comment: TimeSpan, dont have problems adding data regarding their data types, my problem is it only adds 1 data while it queried more than 1 data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should run the query from LinqPad to make sure that your data actually matches your expectations.  Your foreach loop is fine, your query is only returning one result, which makes it a data issue.

Answer (score 0):

`actualTime` gets set as the facultyTime. Which is constantly getting `Add`ed to? I'd guess it's either something in the Add method, or something in the actualTime property setter that isn't going through the whole facultyTime collection (if indeed it is a collection). Some clarity on what these objects are would be helpful in determining the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your query object probably only contains 1 item.  try stepping through it with your debugger.